# Unknown provider: e when moving Angular/Rails app to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

When I push my Rails 4/Angular app to production I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e
```

I should mention it works perfectly in development.
From what I can tell, this is most likely due to Rails minifying the js in production.  The solution most people have used to resolve this is to use a alternate method of injecting dependencies in Angular, which I am doing.  I've been through my application twice now double checking that I've done the proper dependency injection throughout.

One thing that I haven't tried is using arrow functions instead of the traditional `function(){}` notation.  Is this something worth trying?

I'll include my app.js code so you can see how I'm doing things.  I have several controllers and factories but I don't think it is necessary to include those at this moment unless someone thinks I should.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'restangular', 'Devise']);

app.config([
  "$httpProvider",
  function($httpProvider) {
    var token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = token;
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
  }
]);

app.config([
  'RestangularProvider',
  function(RestangularProvider) {


    RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('.json');
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({"content-type": "application/json"});
  }
]);


app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

  $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: '/templates/home/index.html',
      controller: "HomeCtrl"
    })

    .state("providers", {
      url: "/providers",
      abstract: true,
      template: '<div ui-view></div>'
    })

    .state("providers.show", {
      url: "/:id",
      templateUrl: '/templates/providers/show.html',
      controller: "ProviderShowCtrl"

    })

    .state("procedures", {
      url: "/procedures",
      abstract: true,
      template: '<div ui-view></div>'
    })

    .state("procedures.show", {
      url: "/:id",
      templateUrl: '/templates/procedures/show.html',
      controller: "ProcedureShowCtrl"

    });

}]);

app.factory("_", ['$window', function($window){
  return $window._;
}]);
```

Here is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

//= require angular
//= require angular-devise
//= require angular-ui-router.min.js
//= require underscore-min.js
//= require restangular.min.js

//= require_tree .
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If all controllers, services, factories, etc, are being injected as in the example you posted, then they're just fine (if you're not sure, then triple-check that ;) ). The last thing to check if that the files which contain the `ui.router`, `restangular` and `Devise` modules are properly included before the app.js file

Comment: @lealceldeiro I just made an edit with my application.js included.  I believe they are included before app.js.  app.js is included is included in the requre_tree . line right?

Comment: hmmm, that `require_tree` can be the problem, dude, I've used this in grails (which uses the same mechanism) and that have caused some troubles. I'm not sure in your case, though.

Comment: @lealceldeiro how could require_tree be the problem?

Comment: Because it loads all the resources without an specific order. If those files depend on each other that could cause a dependency problem (I'm not sure in this case, though), but if you don't find anything else, you could give that a try.

Comment: @lealceldeiro What exactly should I try? Manually requiring each js file?

Comment: yes, if there are not too much you could try `//= require specific-js-file` (require one by one)... or if there are too many, you  could try require folder by folder  (`//= require_tree <subfolder_of_services>` or something like that with each subfolder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new repository and heroku app.  Then I copied and pasted everything from the original app to the new one, and now everything works  perfectly.